# Meteor Method throw $set empty error when it is not empty

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor, alanning-roles

I have a method that is designed to change user roles. My app uses `alanning:roles` to manage permissions. The method in question is defined like this:

```
/* 8. changeRole */
    'changeRole'({id, oldrole, newrole}){
     console.log('id:',id)
     console.log('oldrole:',oldrole)
     console.log('newrole:',newrole)
      new SimpleSchema({
        id      : { type  :   String },
        oldrole : { type  :   String },
        newrole : { type  :   String }
      }).validate({id, oldrole, newrole})
      if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['superuser'])) {
        Roles.removeUsersFromRoles(id, oldrole)
        Roles.createRole(newrole, {unlessExists: true});
        Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, newrole)
        UserProfiles.update({
          owner : id,
        },{
          $set  : {
            roles: [newrole]
          }
        })
        Meteor.users.update({
          _id   : id,
        },{
          $set  : {
            roles : [newrole]
          }
        })
        return true;
      } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorised!');
      }
    }
```

... and this method gets called on the front end via this call:

```
handleChangeRole = (id, oldrole) => {
    let newrole = theRole;
   /*  console.log('submitting these values', owner, oldrole, newrole) */
    if(!Meteor.userId){
        message.error('You are not authorised to do that!');
    } else {
        Meteor.call('changeRole',{ id, oldrole, newrole }, function(err, result){
            if(!result){
                message.error('Failed to change role for this user');
            } else {
                message.success('User has been successfully assigned a new role')
                setToggleData(!toggleData);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When this gets tested, error message gets thrown `Failed to change role for this user` on the front end, and on the server console, this error occurred `Exception while invoking method 'changeRole' MongoError: '$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$set: {<field>: ...}}`

The `console.log` in the `changeRole` method outputs the correct (not empty) data like so:

```
I20200610-13:32:55.852(8)? id: MnBDne4ge62RMLFAH
I20200610-13:32:55.852(8)? oldrole: student
I20200610-13:32:55.852(8)? newrole: teacher
```

I could not find why the error $set is empty is thrown, when the data exist. AND the funny thing is, THE METHOD WORKS!, and the roles were changed, but the errors persisted. i'm clueless. Help!

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the `alanning:roles` source code

```
addUsersToRoles: function (users, roles, options) {
    if (!users) throw new Error('Missing \'users\' param.')
    if (!roles) throw new Error('Missing \'roles\' param.')

    options = Roles._normalizeOptions(options)

    // ensure arrays
    if (!Array.isArray(users)) users = [users]
    if (!Array.isArray(roles)) roles = [roles]
```

then it may change the roles input value.
Your `newrole` variable is a string, after called that function, it would be an array. Then you call update method with $set of array of array. It may not work.
I didn't test. Just guessing.